# Render points / lines in VisPy when they are very close to each other from OpenStreetMaps in OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, opengl-es-2.0, vispy

I am trying to render simple lines from OpenStreetMaps data. I converted the latitude longitude we get into the pixel coordinates using the Mercator projection yet Opengl isn't able to render points this close by. These are the set of points I have. I can render points with vispy if they are slightly far apart but not from these set of points. For example the commented lines in the code do render the points. So is there a way to make the view frustum sensitive to data this close by.

```
 [[ 64.59411621  40.28605652   0.1       ]
 [ 64.59389496  40.28595352   0.1       ]
 [ 64.59381104  40.28591156   0.1       ]
 [ 64.59369659  40.28584671   0.1       ]
 [ 64.59358978  40.28577423   0.1       ]
 [ 64.59277344  40.28533173   0.1       ]
 [ 64.59257507  40.2852211    0.1       ]
 [ 64.59215546  40.2849884    0.1       ]
 [ 64.59153748  40.2846489    0.1       ]
 [ 64.59139252  40.28466415   0.1       ]
 [ 64.59128571  40.28461456   0.1       ]
 [ 64.59088135  40.28437805   0.1       ]
 [ 64.59063721  40.28423691   0.1       ]
 [ 64.59036255  40.28408813   0.1       ]
 [ 64.59024811  40.28401947   0.1       ]
 [ 64.59013367  40.28395844   0.1       ]
 [ 64.58982086  40.2837944    0.1       ]
 [ 64.58907318  40.28339005   0.1       ]
 [ 64.58789825  40.28277206   0.1       ]
 [ 64.5867157   40.28213882   0.1       ]
 [ 64.58557892  40.2815094    0.1       ]
 [ 64.58435822  40.28086472   0.1       ]
 [ 64.58195496  40.27965927   0.1       ]]
```

The code we use is from vispy examples to render lines (python) which was used to render lines.

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# vispy: gallery 2
""" Show a bunch of lines.
This example demonstrates how multiple line-pieces can be drawn
using one call, by discarting some fragments.

Note that this example uses canvas.context.X() to call gloo functions.
These functions are also available as vispy.gloo.X(), but apply
explicitly to the canvas. We still need to decide which we think is the
preferred API.
"""

import numpy as np
from vispy import gloo
from vispy import app
from vispy.util.transforms import perspective, translate, rotate, ortho

W, H = 400, 400

# Create vertices
n = 100
a_position = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (n, 3)).astype(np.float32)


VERT_SHADER = """
uniform mat4 u_model;
uniform mat4 u_view;
uniform mat4 u_projection;
attribute vec3 a_position;
// attribute float a_id;
// varying float v_id;
void main (void) {
    // v_id = a_id;
    gl_Position = u_projection * u_view * u_model * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
"""

FRAG_SHADER = """
// varying float v_id;
void main()
{
    // float f = fract(v_id);
    // The second useless test is needed on OSX 10.8 (fuck)
    /*
    if( (f > 0.0001) && (f < .9999) )
        discard;
    else */
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
"""


class Canvas(app.Canvas):

    # ---------------------------------
    def __init__(self, buffer):

       #  buffer = np.array([
       # [ -4.42757189e-01,  -5.16471803e-01,  -6.51616335e-01],
       # [  3.70873958e-01,   3.83630782e-01,   1.89464033e-01],
       # [ -9.23565388e-01,   8.84109557e-01,   8.74280035e-01],
       # [  7.06181884e-01,   1.11561500e-01,   4.63272840e-01],
       # [ -2.33703643e-01,   8.74389410e-01,  -7.08803475e-01],
       # [  9.14665759e-01,  -4.91853468e-02,   5.51214755e-01],
       # [ -3.51651721e-02,   9.53544497e-01,   1.13748061e-02],
       # [ -2.00554803e-01,   8.23601604e-01,  -2.01624975e-01],
       # [ -5.78361809e-01,  -7.19190955e-01,  -6.34798348e-01],
       # [  2.07641460e-02,  -9.39733744e-01,  -7.52322018e-01],
       # [ -3.88619483e-01,   6.74676895e-02,  -9.36758697e-01],
       # [  8.96090984e-01,   9.09111351e-02,  -3.39223385e-01],
       # [ -9.60957527e-01,   5.22359312e-01,  -9.29324806e-01]]).astype(np.float32)
    #
    #     buffer = np.array([
    #    [ -4.42757189e-01,  -5.16471803e-01, 0.0],
    #    [  3.70873958e-01,   3.83630782e-01, 0.0],
    #    [ -9.23565388e-01,   8.84109557e-01, 0.0],
    #    [  7.06181884e-01,   1.11561500e-01, 0.0],
    # [  8.96090984e-01,   9.09111351e-02, 0.0],
    #    [ -9.60957527e-01,   5.22359312e-01, 0.0]]).astype(np.float32)

       #  buffer = np.array([
       # [ -4.42757189e-01,  -5.164743803e-01, 0.0],
       # [  3.70873958e-01,   3.83630782e-01, 0.0]]
       #  ).astype(np.float32)
       #
       #  buffer = np.array([
       # [ 6.459411621e-01,  4.028605652e-01,   0.1       ],
       #  [ 6.453389496e-01,  4.028395352e-01,   0.1       ]]).astype(np.float32)

        print(buffer)
        # buffer = a_position
        a_id = np.random.randint(0, high=len(buffer) - 1, size=(len(buffer), 1))
        a_id = np.sort(a_id, axis=0).astype(np.float32)

        app.Canvas.__init__(self, keys='interactive', size=(W, H))

        self.program = gloo.Program(VERT_SHADER, FRAG_SHADER)

        # Set uniform and attribute
        # self.program['a_id'] = gloo.VertexBuffer(a_id)
        self.program['a_position'] = gloo.VertexBuffer(buffer[0:3])

        self.translate = 5
        self.view = translate((0, 0, -self.translate), dtype=np.float32)
        self.model = np.eye(4, dtype=np.float32)

        gloo.set_viewport(0, 0, self.physical_size[0], self.physical_size[1])
        self.projection = perspective(45.0, self.size[0] /
                                      float(self.size[1]), -100.0, 1000.0)

        self.projection = ortho(-200, 200, -200, 200, -100, 100)
        self.program['u_projection'] = self.projection

        self.program['u_model'] = self.model
        self.program['u_view'] = self.view

        self.theta = 0
        self.phi = 0

        self.context.set_clear_color('white')
        self.context.set_state('translucent')

        self.timer = app.Timer('auto', connect=self.on_timer)

        self.show()

    # ---------------------------------
    def on_key_press(self, event):
        if event.text == ' ':
            if self.timer.running:
                self.timer.stop()
            else:
                self.timer.start()

    # ---------------------------------
    def on_timer(self, event):
        self.theta += .5
        self.phi += .5
        self.model = np.dot(rotate(self.theta, (0, 0, 1)),
                            rotate(self.phi, (0, 1, 0)))
        self.program['u_model'] = self.model
        self.update()

    # ---------------------------------
    def on_resize(self, event):
        gloo.set_viewport(0, 0, event.physical_size[0], event.physical_size[1])
        self.projection = perspective(45.0, event.size[0] /
                                      float(event.size[1]), 1.0, 1000.0)
        self.projection = ortho(-200, 200, -200, 200, -100, 100)
        self.program['u_projection'] = self.projection

    # ---------------------------------
    def on_mouse_wheel(self, event):
        self.translate += event.delta[1]
        self.translate = max(2, self.translate)
        self.view = translate((0, 0, -self.translate))
        self.program['u_view'] = self.view
        self.update()

    # ---------------------------------
    def on_draw(self, event):
        self.context.clear()
        self.program.draw('points')


if __name__ == '__main__':


     buffer = np.array([[ 64.59411621,  40.28605652,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.59389496,  40.28595352,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.59381104,  40.28591156,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.59369659,  40.28584671,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.59358978,  40.28577423,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.59277344,  40.28533173,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.59257507,  40.2852211 ,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.59215546,  40.2849884 ,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.59153748,  40.2846489 ,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.59139252,  40.28466415,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.59128571,  40.28461456,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.59088135,  40.28437805,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.59063721,  40.28423691,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.59036255,  40.28408813,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.59024811,  40.28401947,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.59013367,  40.28395844,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.58982086,  40.2837944 ,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.58907318,  40.28339005,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.58789825,  40.28277206,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.5867157 ,  40.28213882,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.58557892,  40.2815094 ,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.58435822,  40.28086472,   0.1       ],
 [ 64.58195496,  40.27965927,   0.1       ]]).astype(np.float32)
        c = Canvas(buffer)
        app.run()
```

Comment: It is really unclear to me what you are trying to achive. It looks like you are drawing lots of stuff to the same pixel. If that is your issue, just change your vertex transformation. Another issue which could come up in this context is floating point precision. If that's the issue, a more appropriate representation of the data would be required.

Comment: I am trying to render some lines from openstreetmap data. Originally OSM data consists of latitude and longitude which are very close in nature. These lat/lon pairs are transformed to screen space using the spherical mercator projection and the result is the set of points you see above. Now the point is how do I render this on screen since the points are very close to each other. GLOSM does the same thing and I can see that their points are close too. So I am trying to figure out what I am missing.

Comment: How close together or far apart these points end up on screen  solely depends on the image section you are visualising,and this one is totally up to you.